# how to show a join query in laravel into a view

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

i am using laravel 5.5 and am trying to show into a view the current data :

```
$data = DB::table('demandes')
  ->join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'demandes.article_id')
  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'demandes.client_id')  
  ->select('demandes.*', 'articles.nom_article', 'users.prenom')
  ->get();
```

i am trying to find how to make a foreach statement even thought its not the same table i am working with ,

here is the demande table :

[table demandes in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNxAC.png)

Comment: You want, how you can list data on view page using foreach loop?

Comment: yes but using those joins above i already listed them before but from a simple table not with the joins

Comment: I've answered. Please let me know if the same you are looking for. I'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few changes in query

```
$data = DB::table('demandes as D')
      ->select('D.*', 'A.nom_article', 'U.prenom')
      ->join('articles as A', 'A.id', '=', 'D.article_id')
      ->join('users as U', 'U.id', '=', 'D.client_id')  
      ->get();
```

Foreach loop on view:

```
@foreach($data as $value)
   {{ $value->nom_article }}
   {{ $value->prenom }}
@endforeach
```

See if the same you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

your foreach is  same , there is noeffect of table structure because your above query only add two column in single row

Comment: i dont exactly get this , because if for exemple i am going to work with foreah ($demandes as $demande) i will only have access to variables in the demandes table and as showed above i am trying to get the article name and user name out of their id from their original tables

Comment: you just put dd() in foreach and look artical name if you add into select in db then its come and avalible to access